# Remove eclipse error marker in persistence.xml definitely

Tags: eclipse, validation, jakarta-ee, persistence.xml

In a Java EE project in Eclipse I've got a marker in my `persistence.xml` that cannot be deleted:

> JAR file "lib/entities.jar" cannot be resolved

My persistence.xml file looks like:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="p2p">
    <jta-data-source>java:/SixAoP2pDS</jta-data-source>
    <jar-file>lib/entities.jar</jar-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="showSql" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

For the current location in my project structure the marker is correct. There is no jar with this name under this path. But after deployment of the ear everything is ok and works correctly.

So I don't want this error marker anymore. But when I exclude the file from validation the error reoccurs after a clean of the project.

Someone knows how to delete it?

Answer (score -1):

restart your server or (be careful) kill duplicated process related to Jboss|Glassfish, or Netbeans|Eclipse.

Comment: The container is not running.